# how to check if directory is online php

Tags: php, joomla

i have this code which will check whether (a) the store is online and (b) the directory */store* is available:

```
<?php

// Set flag that this is a parent file

define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)). '/../store' );

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');


$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');

$filename = '../store/';

if (!$mainframe->getCfg('offline') && file_exists($filename))
        {
    echo "online";
    }

else 
        {
    echo "offline";
        }
?>
```

when the i set the store as offline in my control panel it works fine, however when the directory */store* has it's name changed or is deleted (becomes unavailable) the page generates a server error **whereas it should echo "offline"**. how can i modify it so that when the directory names changes, it changes it echoes "offline"

Comment: If the page is throwing a server error, I do not think it can be handled in this code. You need to find out where that error gets thrown..

Comment: why do you define $filename anyway? it's defined in your constant JPATH_BASE, which contains an absolute path and should be prefered. after all, it'd be interesting to see details on your server error (check PHP logs, since PHP errors are no actual server errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must check the directory *prior* to the initialization of the application, since the application relies on the directory's existence.

```
<?php

// Set flag that this is a parent file
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(realpath(__FILE__)). '/../store' );
if (!file_exists(JPATH_BASE)) {
    echo 'Offline due to missing installation';
    exit(0);
}

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
jimport('joomla.application.component.helper');

$app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
if ($app->getCfg('offline')) {
    echo 'Offline due to configuration setting';
    $app->close();
}
echo 'Online';
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Apologies for the late appreciation.